# How effective execute this kernel in CUDA

Tags: cuda

My test function is like this.

```
DIMENSION 20
POPSIZE 5000

    __global__ void repairT(int* H, int* diff){

        int tidx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 
        int ii = tidx * DIMENSION;

        //if (ii < DIMENSION * POPSIZE)
        //{
            int Hdiff[DIMENSION] = { 0 };
            int diffcount = 0;
            bool isInIndiv = false;

            //complement set H
            for (int i = 1; i <= DIMENSION; i++)
            {
                for (int j = ii; j < ii + DIMENSION; j++) //H for 
                {
                    if (i == H[j])
                    {
                        isInIndiv = isInIndiv || true;
                    }
                }
                if (isInIndiv == false)
                {
                    Hdiff[diffcount] = i;
                    diffcount++;
                }
                else
                    isInIndiv = false;
            }
            // diff to array
            int diffc = ii * DIMENSION;
            for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++)
            {
                diff[diffc] = Hdiff[i];
                diffc++;
            }
        //}
    }
```

I have big 1D array called H (POPSIZE * DIMENSION). And I want create new array diff, which saves missing elements in interval 0-19, 20-39 and so on...

And I need to execute this code effectivly in parralel 5000times
 I tried this but it execute only for interval 0-19 in H

```
dim3 nbThreadsR1(128);
dim3 nbBlocksR1((POPSIZE / nbThreadsR1.x) + 1);
repairT << <nbBlocksR1, nbThreadsR1 >> >(d_H, d_diff);
```

Pls give me some advice.

Comment: no I remove DIMENSION from declaration of ii but now kernel sometimes do wrong calculations, but it works on all array

Answer (score 1):

You access to H and diff is not [coalesced](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory), which means that the memory unit will not be very efficient. You want to either reorder your data or change the code to have coalesced access.

Also, it seems you are reading H[j] a significant number of times. You may want to define another small array Hcache preloading it to avoid excessive reads:

```
        int Hcache[DIMENSION];
        for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) //H for 
        {
            Hcache[j] = H[j+ii];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= DIMENSION; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ii; j++) //H for 
            {
                if (i == Hcache[j])
                {
                    isInIndiv = isInIndiv || true;
                }
            }
            if (isInIndiv == false)
            {
                Hdiff[diffcount] = i;
                diffcount++;
            }
            else
                isInIndiv = false;
        }
```

Finally, you want to make sure that compiler gets enough freedom on registers and your device can handle that many such that Hcache and Hdiff are stored in register file (see maxrregcount option [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#axzz46kUel5m2)).

Comment: I am pretty sure this doesn't answer the question that is (very poorly) being asked

Comment: @talonmies, it is possible. I tried my best to understand the question, and help Petr. I thought pointing out that the repeated reads of same data was very expensive and moving this invariant out of the loop would help improve performance. Should you have a better understanding of the question, please let me know.

Comment: It's actually a "help my code doesn't work question", but there isn't nearly enough detail to provide an answer

Comment: Since Petr asks about how to use this kernel in an efficient way, I think the answer from Florent can still help him, as it points out two implementation aspects impacting performance.